# How to measure the “Skewness” of a Probability Distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

I looked at the "Fisher Measure" formula for "skewness of a probability distribution" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skewness) - this is related to the expectation of the third moment for some transformed probability distribution.

How does this seemingly arbitrary formula using the expectation of the third moment specifically measure how skewed the probability distribution is? In other words, what is the motivation behind it?

Why does this not incorporate, for example, the second or fourth moment? Why even involve moments in this calculation to characterize the skewness of a distribution?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking.  As you have seen from that article, there are quite a few measures of skewness out there...I don't think there's any universal agreement on a "best" one.  The Fisher measure (third moment of standardized distribution) is natural enough, $0$ on the sort of things it should be $0$ on, positive and negative where you'd expect. But if you prefer one of the others, you won't be alone.

Comment: $x^3$ is not symmetric, so $E[(X-\mu)^3]$ will be positive if most values are larger than the mean, and negative if most values are smaller.

Comment: "Why even involve moments...?" Because the totality of all the moments determines the shape of the distribution.

Comment: @LeeMosher Not necessarily, for example the log normal distribution. Need condition such as $\sum_{n\geq 0}\mu_n x^n/n!$ have a positive radius of convergence where $\mu_n = E X^n$.

Comment: in statistics all measures, of skeweness or anything else, are essentially arbitrary: we pick some ones that have some interesting properties over others, usually because they are easier to handle. This is way there is a lot of different measures for skeweness in the wiki you linked

Answer (score 1):

I think the confusion here is that you are assuming that there is one universal way that statisticians define skewness. In actuality there are multiple measures of skewness - many of which are applicable depending on the exact context.

Some examples include:

> **Fisher's Moment Coefficient of Skewness:** $\overline{\mu}_3 := \mathbb{E}\big{(}\big{(}\frac{X- \mu}{\sigma}\big{)}^3\big{)}$
>
> **Mode Skewness:** $\frac{1}{\sigma ^2}$(mean - mode)
>
> **Median Skewness:** $\frac{3}{\sigma ^2}$(mean - median)

And there are many others. Therefore, your confusion as to why the skewness necessarily relates to the 3rd moment is resolved by the fact that this isn't the case. Both the mode and median skewness involve the mean (which is the first moment) and the standard deviation (which is a transformation of the second moment).

The key takeaway is that there are many different measures of skewness involving lots of different moments depending on which definition you are using.

The choice of definition ultimately comes down to the context and some subjective choice on which definition to go with. None of these definitions are "better" than any of the others in all situations. It's up to you to make a personal judgement.

Specifically looking at the Fisher's Moment Coefficient of Skewness (as this is the one that you seem to be referring to in your question), the reason that this works as one potential measure of skewness is that $X- \mu$ will tell you how far away the observations are from the mean and the fact that it is cubed means that you are able to distinguish whether or not $X$ is skewed to the left or the right of the mean. In other words, if the power was even, then you wouldn't be able to distinguish between whether or not $(X - \mu)^{2n}$ was positive or negative. Whereas $(X- \mu)^3$ is sufficient for us to know which direction the data has been skewed in.

Answer (score 1):

If a probability distribution is symmetric around its mean ($\forall \delta: f(\mu - \delta) = f(\mu + \delta)$), then I assume you would agree that it should have a “skewness” of zero.  Odd moments have this property; even moments do not.

But the *first* standardized moment $\frac{E(x) - \mu}{\sigma}$ is always zero, which isn't useful.

That leaves the *third* standardized moment as the lowest-degree one that qualifies as a sensible measure of skewness: Zero for symmetric distributions, and non-zero for *some* distributions.

You *could* try using the fifth or seventh moment, or some other statistic that's not based on moments at all.  Some of them are listed on Wikipedia under [“Other measures of skewness”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skewness#Other_measures_of_skewness).  It's just that Fisher has been traditionally established as *the* skewness coefficient, just as [Pearson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_correlation_coefficient) has been established as *the* measure of correlation between two variables.